# Excel - pull data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 but in incremental steps

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to pull from sheet 1 or `LIVE INFO` down in steps of 28 on sheet 2.

Is there away to do this without Index or manually doing it?

```
='LIVE INFO'!A2
='LIVE INFO'!A30
='LIVE INFO'!A58
='LIVE INFO'!A86
='LIVE INFO'!A114
='LIVE INFO'!A142
='LIVE INFO'!A170
='LIVE INFO'!A198
='LIVE INFO'!A226
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `ROWS` and `INDIRECT` to achieve this:

```
=INDIRECT("'Live Info'!A"&(ROWS($A$1:A1)*28)-26)
```

On it's own `INDIRECT("'Live Info'!A2")` would give you the value of A2 from Live info.

To dynamically get the 2 to increment by step of 28 we calculate, how many rows have passed. multiply this by 28, then subtract 26, as you started on row 2:

```
ROWS($A$1:A1)*28)-26
```